# Как можно написать похожую программу, но без numpy и random?

Tags: python, случайные-числа

```
import numpy
import random


def selection_sort(a):
    for i in range(len(a) - 1):
        ii = i
        for j in range(i + 1, len(a)):
            if a[j] > a[ii]:
                ii = j
        a[i], a[ii] = a[ii], a[i]


n = random.randint(1, 10000)
k = random.randint(1, 100)
b = list(numpy.random.randint(0, 2 * 10 ^ 9, n))
selection_sort(b)
f = (b[k])
print('Количество элементов =', n, 'Необходимо выбрать', k, 'элемент.')
print('Отсортированный массив b равен', b)
print('Выбранный элемент -', f)
```

b здесь - это массив, состоящий из n-ного количества элементов, каждый из которых равен 0 ≤ ai ≤ 2 x 10 ^ 9, а k - элемент массива, который нужно выбрать.

Пример работы программы: C:\Users\DX1\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/DX1/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py
Количество элементов = 5382 Необходимо выбрать 21 элемент.
Отсортированный массив b равен [28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, ... 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
Выбранный элемент - 28

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 2):

Я так понимаю, у вас задание не на сортировку и не на численные вычисления с использованием `numpy`, а на генератор псевдослучайных чисел.

Ну так и сделайте себе генератор. Самый простой вариант - [регистр сдвига с линейной обратной связью](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80_%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C%D1%8E#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8). Если не заморачиваться и взять первую попавшуюся схему из википедии, то может получиться что-то в таком духе:

```
class LSFR_PRNG:
    def __init__(self, S=0xdeadbeef):
        self.S = S & 0xffffffff
    def next(self):
        bit = (((self.S >> 31) ^ (self.S >> 30) ^ (self.S >> 29) ^ (self.S >> 27) ^ (self.S >> 25) ^ self.S ) & 0x00000001 )
        self.S = (self.S >> 1)| (bit << 31)
        return self.S
    def randint(self, left, right=None):
        if right is None:
            left, right = 0, left
        if left > right:
            left, right = right, left
        rng = right - left
        return left + self.next()%rng
```

Тогда тот кусок вашей программы, который использует генераторы случайных чисел, можно переписать вот так:

```
prng = LSFR_PRNG()

n = prng.randint(1, 10000)
k = prng.randint(1, 100)
b = [ prng.randint(2 * 10**9) for _ in range(n) ]
```

Обратите внимание, что `два на десять в девятой степени` в языке Python записывается как `2*10**9`. А то, что написали вы, это оператор `XOR`: `2*10^9 == (2*10) XOR 9 == 29`

Если вы хотите, чтобы при каждом запуске программы получались разные результаты, то регистр сдвига нужно инициализировать каким-нибудь значением, производным от текущего времени. Например, вот так:

```
import time

prng = LSFR_PRNG(hash(time.time()))

n = prng.randint(1, 10000)
k = prng.randint(1, 100)
b = [ prng.randint(2 * 10**9) for _ in range(n) ]
```

Практически гарантированно уникальное значение инициализатора при каждом запуске программы.

Answer (score 0):

Без random теоретически можно, но без библиотек очень сложно. ГСЧ не встроен в питон по умолчанию. Для этого нужен модуль random или ГСЧ из функции random_number. Но учтите, решение из модуля random всегда лучше.

Без numpy и random:

```
import datetime

def random_number(minimum,maximum):
    now = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    rnd = float(now[::-1][:3:])/1000
    return int(minimum + rnd*(maximum-minimum))


def selection_sort(a):
    for i in range(len(a) - 1):
        ii = i
        for j in range(i + 1, len(a)):
            if a[j] > a[ii]:
                ii = j
        a[i], a[ii] = a[ii], a[i]


n = random_number(1, 10000)
k = random_number(1, 100)
b = []
for i in range(n):
    b.append(random_number(0, 2 * 10 ^ 9))
selection_sort(b)
f = b[k]
print('Количество элементов =', n, 'Необходимо выбрать', k, 'элемент.')
print('Отсортированный массив b равен', b)
print('Выбранный элемент -', f)


Но если вы используете фиксированые значения, можете выкинуть random.randint() и заменить на свои циферки
```

Comment: Псевдорандом можно реализовать самостоятельно, взяв какую-нибудь простую хеш-функцию вроде CRC32 и инициализируя её временем (а-ля `srand()` в Сишной библиотеке)

Comment: Можно. Но это костыли.

Comment: это не кастыли, а тз

Comment: Ну вроде теперь без random